# Running Apollo Angular watchQuery() with different variables return the cache data

Tags: angular, typescript, apollo, apollo-angular

So, I am working on a project's feature that allows users to view data based on different variables, for example, data that are unique to years, location, gender etc.

Below is the code that I write:

```
 this._querySubscription = this._apollo.watchQuery({                      
      query: *some graphql query*,
      variables: {
        // this is where the variables are dump 
      }
    })   
    .valueChanges        
    .subscribe(( { data, loading } ) => { 
      do something with the data                            
    })
```

Now, don't worry about the error with the function and stuff because I have got everything right. I even have below code to handle cache and even evict.

```
let cache = this._apollo.client.cache as InMemoryCache
      
        let data = this._apollo.client.cache.readQuery({
          query: *some graphql query*,
          variables: { *using the same variables as the writeQuery, of course*}  
        })
        
        cache.evict({
          fieldName: "*the fieldname from the query*", 
          broadcast: false,
        }); 
        
        this._apollo.client.cache
        .writeQuery({
          query: *some graphql query which is the same as above*,
          data,
          variables: {
            *again, same variables*      
          }  
        })
```

Some of the things that I have come across are:

1. Without using the `readQuery` and `writeQuery`, when running the `watchQuery` again, even with different variables to run the query will return the same data from the cache.
2. Using the `readQuery`, `writeQuery`, `evict` and running the second query with different variables will not return the same data from the cache (which I am looking for) but, if I try to run the first query back, the data return will be empty, probably because I modify the cache.
   3.If you are thinking of using `fetchPolicy` when running the query, I have tried all 4 `fetchPolicy` ,
   `cache-first`, `network-only` etc. It works if I use `cache-network-only` but then somehow I have no idea how to wait for it completely finish making the request and updating the cache before I can update my UI.

Answer (score 1):

I just solved a similar issue you were having and the trick was to call `this._querySubscription.refetch(newVariables)`. That way you shouldn't have to manually delete cache.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem as well when using Apollo. They way I solved was to create a separate module that handle all the Graphql stuff with a Factory, and a `no-cache` on the `.watchQuery` method. I'm sure you can change `fetchPolicy` to accept one of these values:
`'cache-first' | 'network-only' | 'cache-only' | 'no-cache' | 'standby' | 'cache-and-network'` (Values take from `watchQueryOptions.d.ts`).

I'm using the latest version of the packages:

```
"@apollo/client": "^3.2.4",
"apollo-angular": "^2.0.4",
"graphql": "^15.3.0",
```

So, here's the module:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { InMemoryCache } from '@apollo/client/core';
import { Apollo, APOLLO_OPTIONS } from 'apollo-angular';

import { HttpLink } from 'apollo-angular/http';

export function createApollo(httpLink: HttpLink) {
    return {
        link: httpLink.create({
            uri: "/api/...",
            withCredentials: true
        }),
        cache: new InMemoryCache(),
        credentials: 'include',
    };
}

@NgModule({
    exports: [],
    providers: [
        {
            provide: APOLLO_OPTIONS,
            useFactory: createApollo,
            deps: [HttpLink],
        },
    ],
})

export class GraphQLModule {
    constructor(
        apollo: Apollo,
        httpLink: HttpLink
    ) {
        apollo.create({
            link: httpLink.create({
                uri: "/api/...",
                withCredentials: true
            }),
            cache: new InMemoryCache()
        }, "network");
    }
}
```

`tsconfig.json` file needs to be edited with these versions by adding this line:
`"allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true` under `compilerOptions`

Then I call the query in a component:

```
this.apollo
    .watchQuery({
        query: your_query,
            variables: {
                ...your_variables
            },
            returnPartialData: false,
            fetchPolicy: "no-cache" // <----- You may need to change that as I wrote above

        }).valueChanges
        .subscribe((data: any) => {
          foo();
        });
```

Comment: I dont quite understand the use of the module you wrote above? Can you please explain? Also on the second part where you call the query in a component, I tried to use fetchPolicy : no-cache before and it works but this also means that I will have to call the query every single time the variables change. I really want to avoid this as the data is really huge and having to make a query every time a variable change is really something  I want to avoid